# Why ''" == 0 is equal to true?

Tags: javascript

I know the difference between two and three equalitiy.
So when we have

```
2 == '2'
```

it check only for the value so in this case it is trye

and when we have

```
2 === '2'
```

then we have false because the value is same but it also checks the data type. On the left it is number and on the right it is type string.
But in this case

```
0 == ''
```

i don't get it why they are equal. So we are checking the value only not the data type.

Comment: [Wat?!](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison `5. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ! ToNumber(y).`